# Is there a pre-baked ListView that acts like a Radio (or like a Spinner that doesn't hide)?

Tags: android, listview

I'm not averse to rolling my own, but wanted to make sure I'm not overlooking pre-existing functionality.

I need a ListView where each View can take a highlighted state and then be un-selected by virtue of selecting a different item in the list.  Basically a radio list.

I totally understand how to build one myself, so please don't jump down my throat with "what have you tried"... I'm just asking if I'm overlooking a pre-built tool already baked into the Android toolkit.

Comment: err... setting `choice mode = single choice` doesn't work ?

Comment: never noticed that flag... that may indeed be exactly what I need! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either add attribute `android:choiceMode=singleChoice` in layout.

or, 
call `setChoiceMode(AbsListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE)` on `ListView` from your code.

If you need item views to highlight on selection, use `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1` or `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_2` for item layout.